# Request picture(s) for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A friend (Dmitry)  is teaching ODE and asked me for an example, as we were emailing about a book I bought. He asked for "examples of discrete families of periodic solutions, stable alternating with unstable?" My interpretation is to have the periodic solutions be concentric circles in the plane...

Below I give a graph for $y = \sin \left( x + \sin x \right)$ the blue curve.

I do not believe that i currently have an ODE solver or ODE grapher; the fixed view Wolfram Alpha gives is not helpful. Could someone please post a picture with some solutions of
$$  y' =  \sin \left( y + \sin y \right)  \; \; ,$$
maybe $y(0) = \pi / 2,$ also $y(0) = - \pi / 2 \; \; ?$ These should be, roughly, an arctangent curve and an arccotangent curve.

If it is possible, I would also love to see polar coordinates with $r > 0,$
$$  r' =  \sin \left( r + \sin r \right)  \; \; ,$$
maybe $r(0) = \pi / 2,$ also $r(0) = 3 \pi / 2 \; \; ?$
In this case, there will be spirals leaving/approaching the constant solutions, too tight to draw...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried WolframAlpha?

Comment: @Rahul yes, it does not let me zoom in or out, and the piece of curve it shows is not indicative of much

Comment: I wonder, why does your friend needs this kind of weird example?

Comment: @YuriyS he asked for "examples of discrete families of periodic solutions, stable alternating with unstable?" and we were talking about Poincare-Bendixson

Comment: @WillJagy, thank you for the answer. As for the question, you really just need to plot $$x=\int_a^y \frac{dt}{\sin(t+ \sin t)},$$ is this correct?

Comment: @YuriyS I guess so, now that you mention it. I did not think in terms of trying to solve it.

Comment: You can use Mathematica to do that. If you want a free alternative, I would suggest Python with Scipy. It has a good documentation on what it does and a lot of examples online. Look here: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations

Comment: @WillJagy, I would either use numerical integration, or finite differences for the original ODE. It can be done (if you would like to) in any language you prefer. I could do something quick in R, though I'm still new to it. Don't have access to Mathematica right now, or it would have been a matter of seconds to plot the integral or the ODE

Comment: @YuriyS thanks. i already sent this idea to Dmitry (in Texas). Since he is teaching the class, i imagine he has some pretty good plotting software; he can presumably do it himself; he has Mathematica through his department, for example. i did want to see, though, how well I had expressed his requirements.

Comment: @WillJagy: Mathematica copy the command StreamPlot[{1, Sin[y + Sin[y]]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{{0, Pi/2}, Red}, {{0, -Pi/2}, Green}, Automatic}}], NDSolve for the numerical solution and also for both of your problems (ode and polar), try: http://www.bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/slopefields.html

Comment: @Moo thank you, the bluffton page also has an option for showing a solution from a single starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the numerical solution I've got using a first order explicit Euler scheme (lazy, I know, but it works well here):

For $y(0)=\pi/2$:

[image]

For $y(0)=-\pi/2$:

[image]

Here's the code. I do forward propagation from $0$ and then backward propagation from $0$.

```
x0 <- 0;
xm <- 2*pi;
y0 <- pi/2;
N <- 100;
h <- (xm-x0)/N;
j <- 1;
xj <- 0;
yj <- y0;
x <- 0;
y <- y0;
while(j <= N){
            yj <- yj+ sin(yj+sin(yj))*h;
            xj <- xj+h;
            y <- c(y,yj);
            x <- c(x,xj);
            j <- j+1;
};
plot(x,y,type="l",col="red",xlim=c(-xm,xm),ylim=c(0,yj))
j <- 1;
xj <- 0;
yj <- y0;
x <- 0;
y <- y0;
while(j <= N){
            yj <- yj-sin(yj+sin(yj))*h;
            xj <- xj-h;
            y <- c(y,yj);
            x <- c(x,xj);
            j <- j+1;
};
lines(x,y,col="red")
```

---

And the polar case:

For $r(0)=\pi/2$ and $\theta \in [0, 8 \pi]$:

[image]

For $r(0)=3\pi/2$ and $\theta \in [0, 8 \pi]$:

[image]

Here's the code (it's really the same code, you only need to change the coordinates for plotting):

```
X <- y*cos(x);
Y <- y*sin(x);
plot(X,Y,type="l",col="purple")
```

I have also increased $N$ to $500$ to account for the larger range.

Comment: these are very nice, thank you.

Comment: @WillJagy, see the edit as well

Comment: polar as well, good

Comment: I'm not going to change the question. However, this helped, and I think I got an easier expression for polar, just $r' = \sin r$ for $r > 0.$ With $0 < r < \pi,$ a typical orbit is $r = 2 \arctan e^\theta,$ spiralling outward as $\theta$ increases. With $\pi < r < 2 \pi,$ a typical orbit is $r = \pi + 2 \arctan e^{- \theta},$ spiraling back in to constant $r = \pi.$   Probably next out is $r = 2 \pi + 2 \arctan e^{ \theta}.$  I sent that to Dmitry as well, it may take a day before he replies.

Comment: @WillJagy, you can always install R (it's free) and plot the solutions using the script I made (of course, you could improve it with a better numerical scheme as well)

Comment: Thanks. I think I have heard of R. That might be nice; I mostly have added number theory stuff, gp-pari and sage were free, and I can do short jobs with the Magma online service... Also C++ with GMP, the point there being they once let me audit a C++ class so I actually know what I am doing with it.

Comment: @WillJagy, R is mostly for statistics, but it has numerous packages for any kind of computations, and it has a lot of plotting options. I have decided to learn it for experimental data plotting mostly, but it's convenient to do some simple calculations there as well, because it can plot them in real time (I don't even need to save the solution points to a list, I could just add them to the current plot from inside the loop). I don't believe even Mathematica could do it